# In which languages is a string not always truthy?

Tags: syntax, truthiness

Are there any (other) programming languages where string 'false' is not a truthy value?

```
php yes:
echo "<?= ('false'==true) ? 'yes':'no' ?>" | php
yes

python kind of:
>>> print(('false'==True))
False
>>> print(bool('false'))
True
>>>

javascript: no
console.log('false'==true)
false


bash: no
[[ 'false' == true ]] && echo "yes"
[[ 'false' != true ]] && echo no
no

ruby: no
ruby -e "print 'false' == true" 
false
```

This is a pretty general question but it's not as easy as you might think to find an answer in one place

Comment: Probably all strongly typed languages. e.g. `"false"` is a String in Java, not a valid boolean literal. Similar for Pascal. In C this wouldn't work either but mainly because there are no real boolean values in C (zero is considered "false", non-zero is considered true).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name to my horror I also just discovered that in php '0' == false